# Play Store Rejected READ_SMS Permission

Tags: android, google-play-services

[image][image]

I removed sms permission from manifest but playstore not accepting my app manifest. Then also Play store Rejected my App.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [StackOverflow is not Google Customer Service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happen because of new android version 9.In android 9 user can enable and disable particular permission  in app settings. for that you have to handle run time permission.

You have to handle runtime permission in app then upload apk again in play store  once google approve it  App will come again live.

while uploading apk in play store you have to give proper answer to google why you are using particular(sms) permission in the app.

**If you feel no need that permission in app** means remove the permission in manifest and update the app version and upload the playstore.After google review app will come live.

Add in your manifest

```
   <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
```