# How to remove location permissions in react-native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I uploaded my react-native app on PlayStore and I saw that my app "may request permission" to access location.

I do not use location services on application so I want it removed. Is there anyway to find out where location services are potentially used? AndroidManifest.xml does not mention any location services. How do I remove this permission?

I want the "may request access to Location" be removed from the permissions in Play Store when it is uploaded.

Comment: Do you use geolocation function in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission tools:node=”remove” android:name=”EnterPermissionNameHere” />
```

the important part is the attribute `tools:node=”remove”`this way it will try to remove the permission if its added from somewhere within the app. Just Make sure to replace "EnterPermissionNameHere" with the exact permission name for example "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Maybe this will fix your problem

Comment: Where is this ```androidManifest``` file?

Answer (score 2):

adding this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.blah.blah">
        .......
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

reference : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170

Answer (score 0):

May be some of  third party used locations services which you integrated in your app.

you should remove like this

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
tools:node="remove" />
```

Increase apk version and upload in play store .if its not accept then  go to appeal for playstore team manually.

for more details Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492598/play-store-rejected-read-sms-permission/55492725#55492725)